# Serverless Error AWS profile "" doesn't seem to be configured?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

It's my first time working around AWS and I'm trying to run an API through serverless. I'm not sure how to configure AWS profile. I can't seem to find much information about it online either. Does anyone have maybe a link? or something to lead me in a direction?

Comment: @Marcin It worked! Thanks for the help! I forgot to respond to this thread my apologies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to setup AWS config profiles is explaiend in [Named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html). Once you set it up, in the serverless framework you use [--aws-profile](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/) option to specify which profile to use, e.g.:

```
serverless deploy --aws-profile <my_profile>
```

Comment: I needed to change `--aws-profile <my_profile>` in `--aws-profile=<my_profile>`

Answer (score 2):

If you still have an issue after configuring the named profile, be sure to set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1. That forces the SDK to load the shared profile. I ran into this issue when the profile has `role_arn` set and does not have access/secret keys configured.